# Using ```localStorage``` to store dynamically created buttons in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

My goal is to have the user enter values which then generates a button. They should be able to continuously enter values and new buttons should be created following each entry.

My current code allows for the creation of one button, but as soon the form is submitted, the page refreshes and the button is gone. How can I store them so that they stay on the page?

My code:

```
         <script>
            var counter = 0;
            function createButton(){
                var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                x.className = "second";
                var name = document.querySelector("#id_goal").value;
                var t = document.createTextNode(name);
                x.appendChild(t);
                document.getElementById("space_holder").appendChild(x);
                var insideclass = document.getElementsByClassName("second");
                insideclass[counter].innerHTML = `<input type="button" onclick="location.href='/inside_goal'" value="${name}"/>`;
                counter = counter+1;
            };
        </script>

        <h1 id = "home_header" style = "font-family: optima; text-align: center"> Nancy Dong </h1>
     <div id = "enter.goal">
         <form id = "subBox" onsubmit="createButton();" method="post">
             {% csrf_token %}
             {{ form }}
             <input type="submit", value = "Enter Goal">
         </form>

     </div>
     <div id = "space_holder" style = "top: 50px; left: 50px;">
     </div>
```

Django Views.py

```
class NewGoalForm(forms.Form):
   goal = forms.CharField(label="new goal")


def index(request):
   return render(request, "index.html",{
       "form": NewGoalForm()
   })
```

Comment: `localStorage` isn't used in your code

Comment: That is correct. I don't understand how to use ```localStorage.setItem()``` for something that is generated dynamically. @ChayimFriedman

Comment: Did the OP already consider an approach which does send the form data but does not reload the page entirely? Something based on the [*Fetch API*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or the many [`XHR`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) related libraries?

Comment: @PeterSeliger, Thanks, I will look at it. But ideally, the button should stay after reloading, because if the user enters another page and comes back, reloading would still occur.

Comment: Where does the element identified as `id_goal` come from? Where is it located?

Comment: @PeterSeliger that is a field that is autogenerated by Django's form